# friend declaration declares a non-template function for sub-class of template class

Tags: c++, linux

I am building a non-standard data structure template. There are many other components to the class and sub-class, but I believe this is the relevant bits.

```
template<typename T>
class my_data_struct {
    //data struct things
public:
    class iterator {
        int _index;
        //iterator things
    public:
        friend bool operator==(const iterator l, const iterator r) 
             { return l._index == r._index; }
    };
    friend bool operator==(const iterator l, const iterator r);
};
```

When compiling on linux I get

```
warning: friend declaration ‘bool operator==(my_data_struct<T>::iterator, my_data_struct<T>::iterator)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]         
  friend bool operator==(const iterator l, const iterator r); 

note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
```

I'm not sure what the note means because the declaration is already inside the class template. Any ideas why I'm getting this warning and how to fix it?

Edit:
I seem to have overlooked the original reason why the operators needed to be friends with the parent class. The operators reference a private member of the parent class. While I could certainly work while ignoring the warning, I'm still interested in knowing the cause.

Comment: It seems you don't need to be `friend` of `my_data_struct`...

Comment: If you *do* need to access private members of `my_data_struct` in `operator==`, then either disable the warning around the extra declaration, or provide utilities in `iterator` to do so. [In the second approach, `iterator` is a bit like an attorney](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Friendship_and_the_Attorney-Client).

Comment: It's quite unusual for an iterator (or it's `friend` `operator==`) to need to access private members in the objects it iterates over so if you don't have a good motivation for it, just remove it. Also, iterators are supposed to be cheap to copy and `//iterator things` suggests that yours isn't. In that case, you should definitely take the iterators by reference in your `operator==`.